# Facebook Graph API v2.4 not returning extended user data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app that uses the Facebook Graph API to implement FB auth integration. As part of this, we fetch the user's email, first_name, and last_name from Facebook so we can either match the email address with an existing user in our database, or create a new user failing that.

In the Graph version 2.3 we could easily get this information with the following request, which you can test-run in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), assuming that we provided an access token having the permissions `user_about_me` and `email`:

```
Request: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/10154900171335022
Response: 
{
  "id": "123456",
  "email": "buckeroo.banzai@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "Buckeroo",
  "gender": "male",
  "last_name": "Banzai",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/123456/",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "name": "Buckeroo Banzai",
  "timezone": -4,
  "updated_time": "2015-06-06T07:21:23+0000",
  "verified": true
}
```

But when I switch to API v2.4 and try the same request, even when I **enable all permissions**, I get the following useless response:

```
{
  "name": "Topher Hunt",
  "id": "10154900171335022"
}
```

This doesn't match FB's API docs, which suggest that the full data (including email) should still be returned as it was in v2.3.

Has anyone successfully found a way to get a user's email address when using FB Graph v2.4? Any workarounds? Maybe I should just hold off on upgrading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass the 'fields' parameter with the relevant keyword of permissions. Please note, since the release of Graph API version 2.2 and above, users can deny the permission for a specific data field.

In addition to it, if the user has registered with a phone number then the email field will be returned as NULL.

To access email and about me of an user via HTTP, here is an example:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/10154900171335022?fields=email,about

An example in Javascript.

```
     FB.login(function(response) {
               if(response.authResponse) { //If the user grants permission
                         FB.api('/me?fields=email,about', function(response) {
                           console.log(response.email);
                           console.log(reponse.about);
                         });
               } else {
                                // User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.
               }
    }, {
        scope: 'email,user_about_me'
    );
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my {app-id}/scores
what fields should I supply?
thanks!